# Use 'pass' as a dictionary keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a fairly basic requests script which signs into a website, however I'm running into a problem; the website requires the 'pass' key, however whenever I try to use this python throws an error saying invalid syntax. Here's my code:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'www.a_url.com'
    USERNAME = 'a username'
    PASSWORD = 'a password'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(user=USERNAME, pass=PASSWORD, jsok='1', dologin='Login')
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": 'www.a_referer.com'})
    page = c.get('www.a_page.com')
    print(page.content)
    output = open('test.html','w')
    output.write(str(page.content))
```

And the error I'm given is:

```
    login_data = dict(user=USERNAME, pass=PASSWORD, jsok='1', dologin='Login')
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea how I can force python to ignore the 'pass' and just use it as the dict key?

Comment: `pass` is a keyword in Python

Comment: Yeah I know that, but the website I'm trying to login to uses pass as its key

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `pass` is a keyword, it can't be used as an identifier.  You'll need to use a dict-literal for this:

```
login_data = {
    'user': USERNAME,
    'pass': PASSWORD,
    'jsok': '1',
    'dologin': 'Login',
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Also apparently I can't accept an answer for 11 more minutes but this is definitely solved.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you cannot do so in that syntax. `pass` is a reserved keyword for python, such as `return`.

The alternative way of setting arbitrary object as key is to use this syntax:

`login_data = {"user": USERNAME, "pass": PASSWORD, ...}`

This is more generic and you can use anything as key.

`{None: 1, 1: 2, str: int}`

Comment: Well ... not _anything_.  You can use _anything_ that can be hashed as a key.  So ... `{['list!']: 'No dice, TypeError will result'}`

Comment: What avoids the problem is not that "it's more generic", but that string keys are written as strings, not as keyword arguments.